# Unknown language displays in Google Sign-in Page in ios integration

Tags: ios, google-signin

I am Working in integrating gmail sign-in in my ios app,Everything is working perfectly but the language that appearing in Sign-In page is not in English it shows some unknown language.Please provide me a solution.

[image: Click Here to view the screenshot]

Comment: Apparently you are being redirected to Greek Google. Do you have any idea why would it do that? (Are you using a greek VPN/Proxy)?

Comment: Share your GSignIn configuration too. That would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the sign-in language to Greek, as far as I can tell from the provided limited information.

According to [Google Sign in Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in#property-documentation):

There is a following property:

> ***(NSString*) language*** *(read write nonatomic copy)*
>
> The language for sign-in, in the form of [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) language code
>   optionally followed by a dash and ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 region code, such
>   as @"it" or @"pt-PT".
>
> Only set if different from system default.

This property is optional. If you set it, set it before calling signIn.

So all you have to do is, set the language to **"en"** before signing in.

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].language = @"en";
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
```

Comment: i did not get you @NSnoob what should i do to get that in English language?

Comment: Your `GIDSignIn` , presumably. Add your code and I might be able to help you better @Jiyas

Comment: That is not what I am asking Jiyas. Go and read [How to ask a good question on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. Follow the steps mentioned there.

Comment: As per documentation,  On my button click action i had coded this: [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn]; to show that sign-in page

Comment: Before calling the sign in method, add the line I told you. Then tell us if it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the language to downside of your application there is an option to change language